# HTML form validation - filtering unicode (Persian) characters in PHP without using preg_match()

Tags: php, regex, unicode, preg-match

I have HTML form input to be validated. The input should only use Unicode (Persian) letters and numeric nothing else. I used the `preg_match` like this:

```
preg_match('/^[آإأابپتثجچحخدذرزژسشصضطظعغفقکگلمنهۀةوؤیيئءًٌٍَُِّ\s]+$/u',$input);
```

and it works fine on localhost, but as my hosting does not have PCRE with Unicode support installed and I am not going to ask them to install it for me, I am looking for another working way to accomplish this.

Are there any ways in which I can validate unicode input, without using `preg_match()` function?

## Duplicate Flag

Accrding to the duplicate flag, I am not after a PCRE, 'preg_match' way. The linked question is a PCRE 'preg_match' way.

Answer (score 1):

There are some specific [multi-byte functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php) that you may benefit from when PCRE is not compiled with `PCRE_UTF8` flag:

```
mb_regex_encoding('UTF-8');
var_dump(mb_ereg('^[آ-یء\s]+$', "سلام پارسی تست می کنیم آإأابپتثجچحخدذرزژسشصضطظعغفقکگلمنهۀةوؤیيئًٌٍَُِّ"));
// int(1)
```

Here `آ-ی` character range includes more characters than Persian has (actually `U+0622` - `U+06CC`, look at corresponding [Unicode table](http://utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=1536&utf8=string-literal)) also note that no delimiters are specified.